# 2000 Honda Accord Codes?

Tags: honda, accord, diy

Recently my car's check engine light turned on, ever since then every time I attempt to turn on the car it has difficulty turning over. Here are the Codes:
P0300
P0301
P0302
P0303
P0304
P0305
P0306
P1456
I attempted to search Google on the meaning of these codes and i get mixed messages. If someone can clarify what might be the problem that would be greatly appreciated. 
2000 Honda Accord LX V6

Comment: I can add this as an answer if it works out, but I would check the EVAP purge valve.  You can test it by removing it and blowing through it.  If you can blow through it even a little bit it's bad.

Comment: @user288719 much appreciated, if you don't mind could you let me know where I can locate that. I'm searching yet can't find anything specific that matches my cars make and model. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't add images in a comment I had to add as an answer.  Apparently Honda called the valve in question a two way valve.

[image]

Comment: Although you can link to pictures in comments...

Comment: The two way valve is not the purge solenoid. The purge solenoid is located in the engine compartment.

Comment: That's what I thought,  but there is no mention of it on the parts breakdown. Not sure if I have an incomplete revision or what.

Answer (score 1):

P1456 -small evap leak detected. Very common problem on Honda. I appears to be the O ring on the filler pipe assembly.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wac6F2JUVSo

Code P0300 - Causes and Fixes

Code P0300 is a code that is generated when your engine has a misfire that is not related to only one cylinder.

Sometimes this code will be set in addition to other codes such as P0301 which means that there is a misfire on cylinder 1 (cylinder 1 is the number one cylinder when looking at the firing order. It is generally the forward most cylinder on the engine.). If these engine codes are present as well the you should diagnose those first as they are probably causing this trouble code.

This code will set your check engine light and needs to be fixed as soon as possible. If it is not then you will probably need to replace your catalytic converter as well as the problem that is causing your misfire.

There are many causes for this OBD code. Since it is a "random misfire" or "multiple misfire" this means that the misfire is on different cylinders and not just one all the time.
What Causes a P0300 Code?

```
Low Fuel Pressure
Vacuum Leak
EGR system malfunction
Internal Engine Problems (such as low compression)
```

Less Common Causes

```
Faulty Coil
Faulty Spark Plugs and/or Wires
Camshaft or Crankshaft sensors
Ignition module
Computer
```

To troubleshoot, repair and maintain your vehicle, you'll need diagnostic and repair information that is specific to your car or truck.

http://www.myautorepairadvice.com/p0300.html

Comment: If it's the O ring why would that cause such a harsh turn over. The engine has a hard time. Really curious....

Comment: The hard turnover could be another issue not addressed in the codes.

Comment: Any idea what it might be? Cause literally when the CEL came on was when the turn started failing.

Comment: By hard turnover: Is it referring to the the engine itself not turning over  i.e cranking ? Or Is it referring to the engine not starting  ie ignition related?

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct.

Comment: The evap issue would make it difficult to start. I had an issue like this an old Corolla. Evap codes can also trigger multiple secondary codes as a result of impacting more than one system. If you have a code reader that shows what issue happened first then you know where to start. I would check out the evap system first. One remedied the other issues might correct themselves.

Comment: For sure I'll work on that O ring and I'll let y'all know how it turned out.

Comment: Hey, so I took apart the the fuel pipe where that gas cap attaches too, and it was an entire piece of solid metal with no spot of an O-Ring. Therefore I bought a new gas cap, assuming that this had to be the issue, I've been driving around for 50-70 miles and CEL turned off. Therefore I'm assuming the leak has been cleared up,  BUT it still has a hard time cranking, engine starts but takes a few seconds of shifting the key to ignite. Is this a spark plug issue now? FYI The ignition coils have just been replaced within a year, so i doubt that'll be it. Again the help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: I truly enjoy learning all of this lol

Comment: I noticed you mentioned shifting the key...It could be a intermittent key switch contact.......The ignition switch is the key (pun not untended) to everything. It is source of power to starter solenoid,the ECM and myriad of other systems...HMMMMMM

Comment: I'm sorry.  I didn't clarify, it's not that I'm shifting the key multiple times in order to start car. It's that when I shift the key i have to hold the position to give the spark plugs time to catch and ignite to start the engine.